# On Debian 8 Cinnamon doesn't start for my normal user. Only as root

Tags: linux, debian, login, su, cinnamon

I was using the OS and suddenly Cinnamon crashed. A modal window asked me if I would restart the desktop environment or not. I clicked no, for error...

Now when I try to access (graphical login) with my normal user, after a few seconds of black screen, I get back to the login page. No errors are shown.

If I access as root Cinnamon works.

Maybe the solution is to reset some configuration or use the one for the root user with my user.

Somebody could help?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved thanks to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

1. accessed via root to the affected user's home directory **~/username**
2. **ls -lah** (to check the .Xauthority file's ownership)
3. **chown username:usergroup .Xauthority** (to change user and group owning the file)

as a **tip** you can check the X error log for your user here /home/username/.xsession-errors